# Is there any chance for me in Information Security field?

Tags: career

I am third-year-student majoring Business administration. However after come to university, I found that I am very interested in Information security and want to pursue this field after graduating. Is there any chance for me? I also want to take part in the undergraduate program of a university in U.S. Is it possible?

Comment: No one can answer what is possible for *you*. No one but the university can tell you if you can take part in their programs. I'm not sure what you are asking, and not sure how an online community can answer these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, You can, 
IT field including InfoSec mostly care about your knowledge,  understanding, and willingness to keep learning and act upon it, 
All most all IT companies looking for the passionate people instead of your paper qualification. in-fact they understand fresh graduates know nothing about the industry, 
Here what I'm suggesting,

- Work on Side projects while you are doing your BA Degree.
  Assuming you have at least a little IT background, you'll need to work o
  projects that give you visibility in the path you are willing to follow.

  - Contribute to Open-Source Projects.

    - Start from the basics, what can I do for Mozilla -> https://whatcanidoformozilla.org , https://github.com/explore check what are the project you can contribute, doesn't matter it's localization, add a fewer line of space in first.even that will helpful for someone in the world.
  - Start your own projects,

    - Doesn't Matter it's basic C program, or forked PHP GitHub project at first , keep work on it until you are familiar with stuff, then you'll figure out your own way occasionally. also, check for open-source InfoSec tools and try to contribute it with Testing, commenting, if possible with feature suggestions and developments,
- IT Security-Based Certification.

  - While you are undergraduate,try to do some certification which gives you visibility and understanding, C|EH, Comptia++ , CISSP (try not to mix everything over your interest), first read about every possible ones and understand what you want to do, most people will disagree with me here, because certifications are not really getting into place where you want to be with knowledge , but for the visibility I believe that's something you'll value, (take these certifications as your ticket to company interviews)
- Network with Right People.

  - Most important thing, Connect with the like-minded and attend to meetups and events where Techies gather, sites such as meetup.com are the places you can find related meetups near you.work with communities Mozilla Campus Clubs (maybe you can start one if your university: https://campus.mozilla.community/ )  , Bsides - http://www.securitybsides.com/ , https://www.owasp.org ( you can also engage or initiate OWASP student Chapter: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Student_Chapters_Program. . 
    Work with the people that engage with certain activities, contribute to projects, read stuff related to infoSec, be an update, test your abilities with demonstration framework, talk to industrial people from the certain organization and ask them what requirement you need to fulfill.

Doing BA won't be a big problem to work in InfoSec field unless you let it be, working in the right way you can make your BA as extra advantage gets into the field.

for the last part in your question `I also want to take part in the undergraduate program of a university in U.S. Is it possible?`
I'm sorry I'm not the right person to answer it since I have less understanding about it. but I think that won't be a issue.